# Is there a way to initiate a script after an ajax response?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My problem is that I am including the scripts needed for the functionality of the html inside of my document. After my ajax requests the chunk of html I want placed in the page the functionality doesn't work. So because the scripts are loading before the ajax call is made the scripts have no way of knowing that there is a new chunk of data in the page.

Is there a way to reload the script after the ajax call is made? Or what would be the best way to go about fixing this issue.

Comment: Yes there are many examples you can find online...google "ajax success function".  Echo data from the function in your controller and if it is being executed you'll see it in your console.

Comment: This is all I needed thanks `$.ajax({url:"http://example.js"});` This question wasn't easy to word at all.

Comment: either delete the question or add that as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The success method should help you

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "anyUrlPhpPage.php",
    data: $("#formId").serialize(), //serialize the form data
    cache: false,
    success: function(msgReturned){
        $("#resultDisplay").html(msgReturned); 
        //display the message in the div with id resultDisplay

    }
});
```